# Meteor Apollo GraphQL Interfaces: return an array of object and invoking resolver in another resolver

Tags: meteor, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm having some issues with [GraphQl interfaces](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/features/unions-interfaces.html#Interface-type). Let take the example in the doc:

```
interface Vehicle {
  maxSpeed: Int
}

type Airplane implements Vehicle {
  maxSpeed: Int
  wingspan: Int
}

type Car implements Vehicle {
  maxSpeed: Int
  licensePlate: String
}

type Query {
  vehicle: Vehicle
}

const resolvers = {
  Vehicle: {
    __resolveType(obj, context, info){
      if(obj.wingspan){
        return 'Airplane';
      }

      if(obj.licensePlate){
        return 'Car';
      }

      return null;
    },
  },
  Query: {
    vehicle: () => { 
       // Query Airplane and Car an merge in one single array.
    }
  },
};
```

Background: I create 2 different `DBs` for each interfaces implementation: one for `Car` and one for `Airplane`. But I did not create a `DB` for `Vehicle` since it just an `interface` that does not keep data in itself. (I hope this is fine)

The first problem is how to access `Car` and `Airplane` `resolvers` to query their respective `DBs` in the `Vehicle resolver`? So in `Query.vehicle()`, I would like to just call the resolver defined for fetching all cars to get all cars and call the one for fetching airplanes to get all airplanes in the DB. (note using `Car.find().fetch()` is not always effective because before doing the query, lots of other query needs to be done also avoid code duplication).

The Second problem is that in the example, `obj.wingspan` assume that `obj` should be an object. So returning an array from `Query.vehicle()`, won't help because this query is used in `Vehicle.__resolveType`. So from what I've experienced with GraphQl interfaces, it only returns a single object from the query.
My aim is to obtain with the with the following query:

```
{
  vehicle {
    maxSpeed

    ... on Car {
            licensePlate
    }
    ... on Airplane {
      wingspan
    }
  }
}
```

the following result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "car": [
      {
        "maxSpeed": 200,
        "licensePlate": 1.8
      },
      {
        "maxSpeed": 120,
        "licensePlate": "String"
      },
      ...
    ],
    "Airplane": [
      {
        "maxSpeed": 500,
        "wingspan": "String"
      },
      {
        "maxSpeed": 700,
        "wingspan": 1.5
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be trying to return multiple objects. If so, you'll need to return an array of objects:

```
type Query {
  vehicles: [ Vehicle ]
}
```

If you're just trying to return a single object by ID, in your vehicle resolver, just try both databases and return the one with the result:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    vehicle: (parent, args) => {
      const { id } = args;

      const [ car, plane ] = await Promise.all(
        await carDB.get(id),
        await planeDB.get(id)
      )

      return car || plane
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit**

In case you didn't already get to this:

To get what you're describing, you would need something else:

type-definitions

```
interface Vehicle {
  maxSpeed: Int
}

type Airplane implements Vehicle {
  maxSpeed: Int
  wingspan: Int
}

type Car implements Vehicle {
  maxSpeed: Int
  licensePlate: String
}

type Query {
  vehicles: VehiclesConnection
}

type VehiclesConnection {
  car: [ Car ]
  airplane: [ Airplane ]
}
```

resolvers

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    vehicle: () => {
      const [ cars, planes ] = await Promise.all(
        await carDB.findAll(),
        await planeDB.findAll()
      )

      return { cars, planes }
    }
  }
}
```

query

```
{
  vehicle {
    car {
      maxSpeed
      licensePlate
    }
    airplane {
      maxSpeed
      wingspan
    }
  }
}
```

alternate query

```
{
  vehicle {
    car {
      ...VehicleFragment
    }
    airplane {
      ...VehicleFragment
    }
  }
}

fragment VehicleFragment on Vehicle {
  maxSpeed

  ... on Car {
    licensePlate
  }
  ... on Airplane {
    wingspan
  }
}
```

result

```
{
  "data": {
    "car": [
      {
        "maxSpeed": 200,
        "licensePlate": 1.8
      },
      {
        "maxSpeed": 120,
        "licensePlate": "String"
      },
      ...
    ],
    "Airplane": [
      {
        "maxSpeed": 500,
        "wingspan": "String"
      },
      {
        "maxSpeed": 700,
        "wingspan": 1.5
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already figured that out. What I'm trying to achieve is the result showed above with each DB (Car, Airplane,...) grouped.